# Is there something wrong with this bubble sort code?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, bubble-sort, sorting

```
function algBubble(input:Array):Array{  
var changed:Boolean=true;

while(changed==true){

    changed=false;

    for(var i:int=0; i<input.length-1; i++){

        if(input[i]>input[i+1]){

            var temp:int=input[i];
            input[i]=input[i+1];
            input[i+1]=temp;

            changed==true;
        }
    }
}   
return input;
}
```

It only seems to run through the array once, leaving it mostly unsorted.

Comment: You mean beside the fact that you're using a bubble sort in anything other than a classroom?

Comment: I do not know actionscript, but to me it looks like changed==true should be changed=true.

Comment: @Paul, bubble sort is _fine_ for small data sets and also sometimes for data that's already mostly sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change:

```
changed==true;
```

to:

```
changed = true;
```

The first does a comparison and throws it away, the second actually *sets* `changed` to `true` to indicate that a swap has been done.

Other than that little problem, everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 4):

Change this line

```
changed==true;
```

to

```
changed=true;
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't beleive I missed that

Answer (score 1):

A bubble sort is one of the slowest sorting algorithms ever.

You can sort about anything by using the built in Array.sort function, more information about this [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_3.html#119416)

You can do that as follows:

```
        var test:Array = [5,3,6];

        private function sortArrays():void{
            test.sort(compareFunction);
            trace(test);//will output 3,5,6
        }

        function compareFunction(a:Number, b:Number):Number { 
            if (a<b) { 
                return -1; 
            } else if (a>b) { 
                return 1; 
            } else { 
                return 0; 
            } 
        }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:
`changed==true` should be `changed=true`